# Deadline for withdrawing excess HSA contributions

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa, excess-contribution

Due to changing jobs, I've exceeded by HSA contribution for 2018 by several thousands of dollars. I went to a tax preparer and we've filed form 5329 for tax year 2018 to pay 6% tax on that excess.

Unfortunately I completely forgot about the excess and again contributed the whole amount this year (tax year 2019).

I want to try to return the excess, but the deadline is unclear: Is the deadline January 1st or the tax filing deadline (which is July 15th this year)? For some other excesses like 401k it's tax filing deadline.

Some quotes I've found:

> Any excess contribution remaining at the end of the tax year is subject to the additional tax.
> https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8889#idm139932616530896

> Withdrawing the excess contribution(s) by the tax filing deadline of the year [https://answers.healthequity.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1249/~/hsa-excess-contributions](https://answers.healthequity.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1249/%7E/hsa-excess-contributions) (My HSA operator's website)

P.S. After withdrawing, do I need to request a corrected form  1099-SA and/or 5498-SA? Do I need to a new W-2?

Comment: If it's the same as excess IRA contributions (which also have a 6% excise tax), it applies to contributions remaining as of the tax filing deadline for the year contributed, but then it applies to contributions remaining as of the end of the year for all future years that the contributions remain in. However, a past year's excess can be absorbed into a year's contribution amount if the amount contributed that year is less than the limit, so perhaps it can be thought of as a new excess contribution (which allows you to use the tax deadline) instead of a continuation of the old one.